# Loosing clarity when Resizing the image

Tags: flash, adobe-illustrator

I have created the following image in adobe illustrator.

### Picture 1

[image]

When I reduce the size to 90x90 in flash the image is not sharp as mentioned below

### Picture 2

[image]

how to have the sharp and clear image as I have in the picture 1 even when I reduce the size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Flash Pro, select *Allow smoothing* from the bitmap properties of the image:

[image: smoothing]

This may also be set programmatically by setting the instance smoothing property:

```
smoothing = true;
```

Comment: where is bitmap properties ?

Comment: If this is Flash Pro, right-click on the imported asset in the library and selected _Properties_.

Comment: still it is same.. I just applied transform->scale in illustrator and created the image of required size.. this is far better..

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the original image is made up of vectors only and that all formats along the way are vectors.  The smaller image shown looks like a resized bitmap.

Formats that support vectors include `*.ai` and `*.svg`.  When using Fireworks, `*.png` can also support vectors, but normally it doesn't (Fireworks stores both a bitmap for normal use and vectors in png metadata).

Answer (score 0):

I think that for a reason (If it's raster), you have resized it without applying quality filtering algorithm. Try reducing it elsewhere (Gimp, Photoshop) with at least bilinear filtering.